# read file and replace by a variable

Tags: r

I have a simple text file looks like below.

```
Title
this is my data

#1 2(0) 3 
 N0 2 3 5 !
```

The thing I want to do is to replace **N** in the text file, by variable **i** in a loop below, then simply save it.

```
for (i in 1:2) {

f <- readLines(data)

=== Do something here to replace N in the text by each i ===

write.table(f,file="file_name",quote=FALSE)

}
```

Then I can get files with replaced **N** but nothing changed.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

The code below might help you:

```
fileName = 'file.txt'    # your source file
mystring = readChar(fileName, file.info(fileName)$size)   # reading the file content

for (i in 1:2) {
    index = as.character(i)
    aux = gsub("N", index, mystring) # replacing N by i
    write(aux,file=paste("file_name", index, sep=""))
    #write.table(aux,file=paste("file_name", index, sep=""),quote=FALSE) # choose the best way to  write
}
```

The result is:

**file_name1**

```
$Title
this is my data

#1 2(0) 3 
7(1) 1(0 2) 3 5 !
```

**file_name2**

```
$Title
this is my data

#1 2(0) 3 
7(1) 2(0 2) 3 5 !
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have sorted it out myself.

Comment: Fantastic! Anyway, it's important to have the answer here in case of future related questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
for(i in 1:2){
  f <- readLines("text.txt")
  f <- gsub("N", i, text)
  write.table(f,
          file=paste0("file_name_",i ,".txt"),
          quote=FALSE, 
          row.names = FALSE, 
          col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have sorted it out myself.